# Mailchimp integration in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp, elementor

I have a wordpress website and i want to integrate mailchimp newsletter in it without plugin. I just wanted to know where to put that code in the theme. Please help

!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/cf0156000d526d168141e65a3/5ce0c2e2a0ebfdf658442b15b.js");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you want the plugin ? It's free.

Else the code that you provided is not sufficient. Follow this tutorial :

https://mailchimp.com/fr/help/add-a-signup-form-to-your-website/.

1. Go to your mailchimp dashbord
2. Click on "Manage audience" (at right) and click on signup forms
3. Select "embedded form"
4. Set all your settings
5. Copy and paste the generated code on your website at te place that you want your form to be.